# Dynamically subset from data table in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a very big data set with around 3 Million rows and 13 columns as data table in R . I have copied a sample data--

```
 V1 V2 V3    V4   V5    V6        V7  V8 V9  V10    V11   V12     V13
 1 AAE CDG  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    0  0  1030   1250  0.15335  0
 2 AAE CDG  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    5  5  1130   1350  0.15293  0
 3 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    4  4  1420   1750  0.00100  0
 4 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    0  0  1320   1540  0.18183  0
 5 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    5  5  1320   1540  0.18112  0
 6 AAE TXL  AAE  BER NAFR_UKWEU   2    3  3  1320   1540  0.17799  0
 7 AAE TXL  AAE  BER NAFR_UKWEU   2    1  1  1135   1345  0.15178  0
 8 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    1  1   645   1355  0.04071  0
 9 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    3  3   705   1425  0.01577  0
10 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    3  3   645   1355  0.01430  0
```

I want to dynamically get the subset from the data table on the basis of V4 & V5 as the key. If i have to do it on the sample data given above, i will get three data table in thress steps, as we have three unique combination of V4 & V5. So the desired output is-

```
Step 1- Table 1:
V1 V2 V3    V4   V5    V5         V6  V7 V8  V9     V10   V11      V12
 1 AAE CDG  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    0  0  1030   1250  0.15335  0
 2 AAE CDG  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    5  5  1130   1350  0.15293  0
 3 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    4  4  1420   1750  0.00100  0
 4 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    0  0  1320   1540  0.18183  0
 5 AAE ORY  AAE  PAR NAFR_UKWEU   2    5  5  1320   1540  0.18112  0

 Step 2- Table 2:
 V1 V2 V3    V4   V5    V5        V6  V7 V8  V9     V10   V11      V12
 6 AAE TXL  AAE  BER NAFR_UKWEU   2    3  3  1320   1540  0.17799  0
 7 AAE TXL  AAE  BER NAFR_UKWEU   2    1  1  1135   1345  0.15178  0

 Step 3- Table 3: 

 V1 V2 V3    V4   V5    V5        V6  V7 V8  V9     V10   V11      V12
 8 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    1  1   645   1355  0.04071  0
 9 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    3  3   705   1425  0.01577  0
10 AAL AGP  AAL  AGP  SCAND_SEU   3    3  3   645   1355  0.01430  0
```

Now, Since data is huge there many be many possible combination for V4 & V5, how do we efficiently extract the data for each unique combination of V4 & V5 as the key?

Comment: Pleas tell us what *exactly* you want to do. What does "repeatedly do calculation on subset of data" mean? What calculations? On which subsets? With your data shown above, tell us what you want to do and what the result should be. Then we'll be able to help.

Comment: I think you're looking to get a list of `data.table`s with each combination of V2 and V5? You need to look at `?split`. However, if you can explain what you intend to do with these split-data.tables, maybe there's a better way.

Comment: It's difficult to explain what I want to do, but I will try to explain in nutshell. No I don't want list, I want data table, as I have to merge this with another table to do some basic aggregation exercise. Once, this is done, I will merge back the new data table with additional field to the original table using V1 as the key.

Comment: @Pawan there will probably be a way to do this in a single `data.table` call. No-one can tell you if you don't post an example. Show us the other table and the aggregation you want. Honestly, Arun probably has the barebones of a complete data.table solution already typed up. Fill in the blanks for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not that much idea as to what you want. But I'm going to make an attempt. Assuming your data.table is DT

```
idx <- unique(DT[, list(V4, V5)])
setkey(DT, "V4", "V5")
for (i in seq_len(nrow(idx))) {
    DT[idx[i]] # print(DT[idx[i]]) will show you each subset
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I am really sorry for not giving more detail

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are better ways to handle your issue. Almost never does one run into this issue with data.table. But unless you can explain your problem, this is all one can come up with. For ex: DT[, .SD, by=list(V4, V5)] already gets each subset in .SD for every group. So, you should be doing whatever computations you've in there in `j`.

Comment: If you really have an operation that cannot be done in `j`, there's `out <- list(); x[,out[[.GRP]]<<-.SD,by="V4,V5"]`. 3m rows x 14 columns isn't so big, so duplicating the data like this should be more of a time-waster than a consumer of memory.